# Tray.IO - Creating a NEW list

Tags: list, object

Working with Tray.IO for the first time and I run into an issue after using the object helper to format the data in the object model I need, to add to a NEW list that contains only the new object information. As you can see below I have tried manipulating the object in several ways.

Any help would be very appreciated.
[Tray.IO Items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mjwj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information you've provided, below is how I would approach this situation. I've also included a video link if you'd like to see it done step-by-step.

1. Using the Data Storage connector, you should create a new list by using ‘Append to List’ method, setting the Key to an appropriate name, with the Value coming from object-helpers-2. In addition, you’ll want to Create if missing.
2. Once the new list is created, you’ll need to retrieve the data using another Data Storage connector by using the ‘Get Value’ method, setting the Key to the name of your prior Data Storage step.
3. Finally, update the Key of your List Helpers step to the result of the Data Storage connector used to retrieve the data.

[Link to Video](https://www.loom.com/share/f0202adf9d504df58e6397acbf19c471)

Happy Traygramming!

Grant